# Should furring strips be used to separate EPS foam from drywall?

Tags: drywall, attic

I am finishing an attic and I plan on having batt insulation between the ceiling joists with 2 inch EPS foam running across the ceiling joists. Should furring strips be used between the foam and the drywall or should the drywall be installed right over the foam with longer screws?

Comment: What is the concern you have regarding doing it vs not doing it? Whether screwing into just the foam will be strong enough for supporting ceiling drywall? Or something else?

Comment: I am not aware of any issues or warnings about having EPS (or any other foam board insulation) in contact with drywall.

Comment: I would use your second choice. Longer screw

Comment: 2 inch foam with 1/2 inch drywall and I think I would need to use 4 inch screws.

Answer (score 0):

Furring strips are anchored through to the cement to give the drywall screws something to attach to. Alternatively you could look at one of the foam systems with integrated studs; that was my solution.